# Upload multiple images using AFNetworking in swift

Tags: php, ios, swift, afnetworking

I want to upload multiple images to my website using `AFNetworking` in **swift**, but only the last image in the `array` uploaded .

**swift** script:

```
let url = "http://pathtomysite"
        let afHTTP : AFHTTPRequestSerializer = AFHTTPRequestSerializer()
        let request: NSMutableURLRequest = afHTTP.multipartFormRequestWithMethod("POST", URLString: url, parameters: nil, constructingBodyWithBlock: {(formData: AFMultipartFormData) in
            var i = 0
             for image in upImage {
                 let imageData  : NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image as UIImage, 0.5)!
            formData.appendPartWithFileData(imageData, name: "uploaded_file", fileName: "imagex\(i)x.png", mimeType: "image/png")
            i++
            }
            }, error: nil)
        let managerS : AFURLSessionManager = AFURLSessionManager.init(sessionConfiguration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
        let uploadTask = managerS.uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest(request, progress: nil) { (response, AnyObject, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil){
                print("error")
            }
        }
        uploadTask.resume()
```

**php** script:

```
<?php
$dt = date("Ymdhis");
$fileInfo = pathinfo($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
$file_path = "uploads/";
$file_path = $file_path . basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {

     rename($file_path, 'uploads/' . $dt . '.' . $fileInfo['extension']);
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
let url = "YOUR_URL"
let afHTTP : AFHTTPRequestSerializer = AFHTTPRequestSerializer()
let request: NSMutableURLRequest = afHTTP.multipartFormRequestWithMethod("POST", URLString: url, parameters: nil, constructingBodyWithBlock: {(formData: AFMultipartFormData) in
  for (index, image) in upImage.enumerate() {
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image as UIImage, 0.5)!
    formData.appendPartWithFileData(imageData, name: "uploaded_file[]", fileName: "imagex\(index)x.png", mimeType: "image/png")
  }
  }, error: nil)
let managerS : AFURLSessionManager = AFURLSessionManager.init(sessionConfiguration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
let uploadTask = managerS.uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest(request, progress: nil) { (response, AnyObject, error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil){
    print("error")
  }
}
uploadTask.resume()
```

and change your script to the following:

```
foreach ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"] as $index => $tmp_name) {
    $filePath = "uploads/" . basename($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"][$index]);
    if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $filePath)) {
        // rename like you want to
    }
}
```

the important piece is adding brackets to the **uploaded_file[]** in your upload code. if you do not include the **[]** every image upload overrides the last one.

the other important piece is the **foreach loop** in your script that handles multiple uploaded images instead of just one.